# Need help for organize postdata

Tags: python, python-requests

I Need help for organize postdata in requests (PYTHON3)

Postdata

```
utf8=✓&authenticity_token=wD7kMBoNOrH4a8WzhxpVuVT7ZHrGtIf7IFySfo8VabYvh 0eAgzauY5pova Iuo57u nZVb4hzatN1GRQe6Ppw==&user[pid]=&user[email]=example@gmail.com&user[password]=123456&user[remember_me]=1&user[unique_token]=
```

I'm doing this with my code

```
import requests
import re

web = requests.Session()
site_token = web.get("https://www.enjoei.com.br/usuario/identifique-se")
get_token = re.search('<form class="Search js-ui-search" role="search" data-search-auto-init="true" action="/busca" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;"/><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="(.+?)"/>', site_token.text).group(1)
req = web.post("https://www.enjoei.com.br/usuario/identifique-se",
    data={"utf8":"✓", "authenticity_token":get_token, "user[pid]", "user[email]":"example@gmail.com", "user[password]":"123456", "user[remember_me]":"1", "user[unique_token]="})
print(get_token)
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\LUCAS\Desktop\Enjoei.py", line 10
    data={"utf8":"✓", "authenticity_token":get_token, "user[pid]", "user[email]":"example@gmail.com", "user[password]":"123456", "user[remember_me]":"1", "user[unique_token]="})
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `data` needs to be a dictionary. The syntax for dictionaries is `{key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}`. And they key `"user[pid]"` is missing its value (as is `"user[unique_token]="`).

Comment: data is a dictionary where the structure is `{key1: value1, key2: value2, ..., keyn: valuen}`, in your case `"user[pid]"` is a key or a value ?, if it is a key which is the associated value or vice versa if it is a value which is the key? What output do you expect?

Comment: "user [pid]" is a value